# Mithril: difference between vnode.attrs and vnode.state

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

What is the difference between `vnode.attrs.value` and `vnode.state.value` when creating new components in Mithril?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://mithril.js.org/vnodes.html):

## State

> An object that is persisted between redraws. It is provided by the
> core engine when needed. In POJO component vnodes, the state inherits
> prototypically from the component object/class. In class component
> vnodes it is an instance of the class. In closure components it is the
> object returned by the closure.

## Attrs

> A hashmap of DOM attributes, events, properties and lifecycle methods.

For example give a look to this code.

```
class Hello {
    
    constructor(height, width) {
      this.txt = 'from state'
    }

    view (vnode) {
            console.log(vnode.state)
        return m("main", [
            m("h1", {class: "title"}, "This come "+vnode.attrs.txt),
            m("h1", {class: "title"}, "This come "+vnode.state.txt)
        ])
    }
}

m.mount(root, {view: function () {return m(Hello, {txt: 'from attribute'})}})
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzL8yyL1/)

The output will show you that state is initialized from the component constructor. The attrs instead are passed from the m().

Generically you can use attrs to pass data to an object when using it in a context (es. pass an URL to a component for ajax usage). Instead use state to persist local data of the component across redraws (es. field initial state for reset purpouse)